# terminal command | grep IP

Tags: command-line, grep, osx, ip, macintosh

```
ifconfig -a | grep  10.16
     inet 10.16.x.xx netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.16.x.xxx
     inet 10.16.x.xx netmask 0xffffff80 broadcast 10.16.x.xxx
```

I have replaced the numbers with `x`

My aim is to remove everything apart from the inet IP's. so it just shows as:

```
10.16.x.xx
10.16.x.xx
```

Is this possible? whilst keeping the command as simple as possible and for it to work across multiple OS (10.9/10.10/10.11)

Comment: are you working on MacOS?

Comment: `ifconfig -a | grep 10.16 | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b"` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482951/extracting-ip-address-from-a-line-from-ifconfig-output-with-grep))

Answer (score 8):

Well, if you know your IP starts with `10.16`, it's trivial:

```
ifconfig -a | grep -oP '\b10\.16\.[0-9.]+\b'
```

Or, if your `grep` doesn't support `-P` or `-o`:

```
ifconfig -a | awk '/10\.16\./ && /inet/{print $2}'
```

If not, you could find all lines starting with `inet` and print their second field:

```
ifconfig -a | awk '$1=="inet"{print $2}'
```

That, however, would also return `127.0.0.1`, the localhost. To avoid that, you could do:

```
ifconfig -a | awk '$1=="inet" && $5=="broadcast"{print $2}'
```

I don't have a mac to test this on, but in general, `ifconfig` is getting deprecated in favor of `ip`. You might want to consider using this instead:

```
ip addr show | awk -F'[ /]*' '$2=="inet" && $5=="brd"{print $3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all inet IP:

```
ifconfig -a | grep -oP 'inet \K\S+'
```

In order to get just 10.16 family:

```
ifconfig -a | grep -oP 'inet \K10\.16\S+'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ip addr show` with `-o` flag. For instance, here's all IPv4 addresses of my connected interfaces

```
$ ip -4 -o addr show  | awk '{print $4}'                                                                                 
127.0.0.1/8
10.42.0.1/24
192.168.0.78/24
10.0.3.1/24
```

Getting only specific addresses that start with `10.` like you have can be done this way:

```
$ ip -4 -o addr show  | awk '/10\./{print $4}'                                                                           
10.42.0.1/24
10.0.3.1/24
```

Stripping the CIDR notation can be done like so:

```
$ ip -4 -o addr show  | awk '/10\./{gsub(/\//," ");print $4}'                                                            
10.42.0.1
10.0.3.1
```

Comment: This question was migrated from AskUbuntu , once it was apparent that OP uses Mac OS X. OS X does not have `ip` command but there exists a wrapper for it. Consult this question: http://superuser.com/a/898971/418028 Otherwise , this solution is applicable for Linux systems

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

`ifconfig -a | grep -e "inet [0-9]" | cut -d" " -f 2`

Most of the given answers won't work well on Mac OS X! The easiest thing you can do, is using `cut` or `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `perl`-command like

```
perl -ne '$_=~/inet\s(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s/; print $1,"\n"'
```

This uses a regex to find the IP after *inet* and prints it. Just pipe your output through it.

Example:

```
ifconfig -a | grep  10.16 | perl -ne '$_=~/inet\s(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s/; print $1,"\n"'
```

Comment: You could shorten that to `ifconfig -a | perl -ne 's/.*?\b(10\.16\.\d+\.\d+)\b.*/$1/ && print'` or, at least  `ifconfig -a | perl -lne '/inet\s(10\.16\.\d+\.\d+)\b/ && print $1'`, there's no reason to use `grep` if you're already passing to Perl.

Comment: yes, true. I wanted to change as least as possible on OP's command. So I just added a perl snippet

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Linux : Get all IPs except localhost :

```
ifconfig -a | grep "inet addr:" | grep  -v "127.0.0.1" | sed -e "s#addr:##g" | awk '{print $2}'
```